# Add downloadable executable to website

Tags: asp.net, build, download, installation

I have a website project, and an outlook addin that communicates via a webservice to the same database. I'd like to add the outlook addin as "downloadable file" to the interface of the website.

How to achieve that *at build time* the outlook addin installer ends up in the website's "Download" folder?

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add a post-build event to copy the addin to the download folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is really a good idea, because maybe not *every* time you build it it is ok to upload it (broken builds? untested bugs?), but anyway, the idea might be this:

- find a way to mount the FTP site mounted as disk Z in the computer and keep it there
- you probably want to zip it before, so find and install a command line zip.exe
- find a way to have an automated job start every few minutes (like a batch file)

The job (might be a batch file) should do this:

- check the file creation date of C:\build\folder\executable.exe and compare it with the file creation date of Z:\download\folder\executable.zip
- only if newer, zip C:\build\folder\executable.exe to C:\build\folder\executable.zip and copy C:\build\folder\executable.zip to Z:\download\folder\executable.zip

In what language you write the script is your choice, a windows batch could do (the XCOPY command can copy only newer files), I know PHP and probably would use that with a batch file calling "php my_php_task.php", but you can launch any language interpreter you like.

**UPDATE**

For zipping you can download this:
http://www.info-zip.org/Zip.html

For copying only newer files u can use XCOPY with options /D (newer only) and /Y (confirm overwriting). Other options here:
http://www.computerhope.com/xcopyhlp.htm

So the batch file might look just similar to these two lines:

```
zip -f C:\build\folder\executable.zip C:\build\folder\executable.exe
xcopy /D /Y C:\build\folder\executable.zip Z:\download\folder\executable.zip
```

Have it called every 30 seconds and the job is done. The -f option in zip and /D option in xcopy make sure the script does nothing except check creation dates if you have not recently rebuilt the file.

Comment: Sorry, I think my post is not very clear. We have a build and a deploy cycle. The deploy pretty much copies the directories from the build into a deploy environment. Thus, when I copy the executable at build time into the website (while the website is being built) , then at deploy time I don't have to do anything manual. So all I am looking for is to copy the executable at build time into my project environment (like a project reference, but VS won't allow me to add a project reference to a setup project.) Am I making any sense?

Comment: Not sure I get it, but the timed-batch approach lets you copy files anywhere you wish, just use the appropriate paths, if it is just a file or directory copy (in the filesystem) you need. If you want to add the files to a project, I can't help, but maybe if you already added them once, just updating the filesystem with the new files will be ok.. You can skip the zip part and just automate XCOPY /D /Y any/file/source.exe any/file/dest.exe